# Symfony2.8, add knpPaginatorBundle witout composer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, knppaginator

I'm using symfony2.8 and I'd like to add **knpPaginatorBundle** to an existing project **without composer.phar** because **I don't have an SSH access**

I have downloaded the bundle **.zip** and I have putted it in the vendor:

[image]

I have activeted it in appKernel and I have added the configuration in config.yml and I have declared it in app/autoload.php like this:

```
/** @var ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

$loader->add('PaginatorBundle',__DIR__ . '/../vendor/KnpPaginatorBundle');

return $loader;
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Class "Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Paginate\PaginationSubscriber" used for service "knp_paginator.subscriber.paginate" cannot be found. in /homepages/21/d676354179/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/DependencyInjection/RegisterListenersPass.php:105 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/21/d676354179/htdocs/vendor/KnpPaginatorBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/PaginatorConfigurationPass.php(24): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\DependencyInjection\RegisterListenersPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #1 /homepages/21/d676354179/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php(120): Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PaginatorConfigurationPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #2 /homepages/21/d676354179/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Componen in /homepages/21/d676354179/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/DependencyInjection/RegisterListenersPass.php on line 105

Comment: Why not composer install it  on another system and upload the resulting files including composer.*? Hint: your folder in the vendor dir is wrong

Comment: The website is online on server , and I I don't have ans SSH, so I can't use composer

Comment: you do not need ssh access to deploy this application, do the composer stuff locally, test locally and ship the application however you have access - since you have been able to upload something that is enough